# Get product collection for products with default name attribute

Tags: magento-1.9

How do you get a collection of products that do not have a name attribute set for a specific store?

Answer (score 0):

in .phtml

```
   $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $collection = $productCollection->create()
      ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
      ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
      ->load();
```

Comment: Does this work for Magento 1.9.x? Looks like Magento 2 code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this :

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
// Put in the array below the attributes you want to select
$products->addAttributeToSelect(array('name'));
// Join to get the name
$nameAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'name');
$nameTable = $nameAttribute->getBackendTable();
$nameId = $nameAttribute->getAttributeId();
// Get default store status value (optionnal)
$products->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('nt' => $nameTable),
    'nt.attribute_id=' . $nameId . ' AND nt.entity_id = e.entity_id AND nt.store_id = 0',
    array('name_default' => new Zend_Db_Expr('nt.value'))
);
// Get specific store values
$products->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('nts' => $nameTable),
    'nts.attribute_id=' . $nameId . ' AND nts.entity_id = e.entity_id AND nts.store_id > 0',
    array('name_specific' => new Zend_Db_Expr('nts.value'))
);
// Select only if no store specific value
$products->getSelect()->where('nts.value is null');
$products->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
```